# Moonlight not working on chromium

Tags: chromium, moonlight

Today i tried to install moonlight plugin for chromium (novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.crx).

It says it's installed but when i try to open sites requiring silverlight it shows the "Get silverlight" button.

I don't know how to fix this and i really want to keep using chromium instead of FireFox

Thanks, michael

EDIT: I haven't tried it on FireFox yet

Comment: Moonlight hasn't been maintained for severald years and even when development was active it was still far behind the silverlight plugin.

Comment: If Moonlight uses the NPAPI plugin architecture (and if it isn't maintained, it likely does), then it is no longer supported in Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try pipelight, instead -

[These instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html) from webupd8 worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: Thanks, found that one out too, sadly enough it only installs the plugin on FireFox and not on chromium

Comment: Hmm. There's a note in there about what to do if it doesn't work in chrome / chromium -- I think I had a bit of trouble getting it to work in all the chrome, but it wasn't too much hassle --  if you try, it shouldn't be too hard. Did you disable the native flash plugin in chrome? Also, does it work in chromium? -- Don't give up - !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> sudo apt-get install moonlight-plugin-chromium

or downloading from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight) or [here](http://dennygoot.blogspot.com/2012/0...irefox-on.html)

if they don't work the apt protocol is not enabled in your browser.

Download chrome .dep file into your desktop. (Google Search)

Then type this command in the terminal

> sudo dpkg -i Desktop/google-chrome*.deb

Login with our gmail account and try to open silverlight.

Comment: The apt-get command gives package not found, go.mono.com/moonlight doesn't distrubute any files and dennygoot.blogspot.com 404's